# recyle application pool,Warm up scripts-Performance tuning in Sharepoint WCM site

Tags: sharepoint

I was trying to tune WCM public facing site we have in Sharepoint . I have following doubts

By default application pools are set to recycle themselves at 2 am in night and because of that we need warm up scripts . But As I was googling on this topic I found mixed reactions on this some MVP are saying its not advisable to recycle application pool daily and some say otherwise so I am confused.

Because if I am not doing recycling application pool then I don't hv to use warmup scripts . But as my site is public facing and its all around the globe so is it advisable that I should recycle it daily as it will affect the performance of my site even though I would run warm up scripts once I don't think so it wud be as good as it should be ....Any advice on that?

Comment: this question appears better suited to Server Fault.  please don't crosspost; it will be migrated there shortly.  you will need to register an account on Server Fault and associate your accounts (in your profile's accounts tab) to regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you don't recycle the app pool regularly **during** any scheduled jobs on your web application. Other than that I don't see any reason why recycling the app pool daily would cause an issue.